# Last known value or 0, else NULL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to

- get row **for each combination of date_ and name_ - param_ tuple**
- and repeat last known value **or** convert NULL to 0 **or** display NULL if brand new row (i.e. no combination of date_, name_, param_ exists)

**Input**

```
NAME_   DATE_   PARAM_  VALUE
A   16-09-2023  A1      NULL
A   16-09-2023  A2      11
A   17-09-2023  A2      10
A   17-09-2023  A3      0
A   18-09-2023  A1      12
B   16-09-2023  B1      2
B   18-09-2023  B1      NULL
B   18-09-2023  B2      4
```

**Expected**

```
NAME_   DATE_   PARAM   VALUE
A   16-09-2023  A1      0
A   16-09-2023  A2      11
A   16-09-2023  A3      NULL
A   17-09-2023  A1      10
A   17-09-2023  A2      10
A   17-09-2023  A3      0
A   18-09-2023  A1      12
A   18-09-2023  A2      10
A   18-09-2023  A3      0
B   16-09-2023  B1      2
B   16-09-2023  B2      NULL
B   17-09-2023  B1      2
B   17-09-2023  B2      NULL
B   18-09-2023  B1      0
B   18-09-2023  B2      4
```

**Attempt**

```
WITH Dates AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT DATE_ AS date_value
  FROM test
),
NameParam AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT NAME_, PARAM_
  FROM test
)
SELECT
  npc.NAME_,
  d.date_value AS DATE_,
  npc.PARAM_,
  NVL(yt.VALUE_, 0) as VALUE_
FROM Dates d
CROSS JOIN NameParam npc
LEFT JOIN test yt
  ON d.date_value = yt.DATE_
  AND npc.NAME_ = yt.NAME_
  AND npc.PARAM_ = yt.PARAM_
ORDER BY npc.NAME_, d.date_value, npc.PARAM_
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/AnULoV80)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find all the dates and then use a `PARTITION`ed `OUTER JOIN` to join it to the table and then use the `LAST_VALUE` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT  t.name_,
        d.date_,
        t.param_,
        LAST_VALUE(t.value) IGNORE NULLS
          OVER (PARTITION BY t.name_, t.param_ ORDER BY d.date_)
          AS value
FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT date_ FROM table_name) d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
          SELECT name_,
                 date_,
                 param_,
                 COALESCE(value, 0) AS value
          FROM   table_name
        ) t
        PARTITION BY (name_, param_)
        ON (t.date_ = d.date_)
ORDER BY name_, date_, param_
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME_, DATE_, PARAM_, VALUE) AS
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-16', 'A1', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-16', 'A2',   11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-17', 'A2',   10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-17', 'A3',    0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A', DATE '2023-09-18', 'A1',   12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-16', 'B1',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-18', 'B1', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', DATE '2023-09-18', 'B2',    4 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| NAME_ | DATE_ | PARAM_ | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | A1 | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | A2 | 11 |
| A | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | A3 | *null* |
| A | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | A1 | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | A2 | 10 |
| A | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | A3 | 0 |
| A | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | A1 | 12 |
| A | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | A2 | 10 |
| A | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | A3 | 0 |
| B | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | B1 | 2 |
| B | 2023-09-16 00:00:00 | B2 | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | B1 | 2 |
| B | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 | B2 | *null* |
| B | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | B1 | 0 |
| B | 2023-09-18 00:00:00 | B2 | 4 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7AqzraOx)